# Snowflake - Using db variables when granting schema access

Tags: variables, schema, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-grant

I'm trying to put together some re-usable scripts to create my databases across multiple environments (prod/ppt/dev) not to mention re-using across businesses. I've come across a snag trying to grant access to specific schemas when my warehouse is referenced by a variable. It doesn't seem to resolve the variable and tells me the schema doesn't exist.

So I'm using something similar to the below:

```sql
    set dbname = 'mydb';
    set role = 'myrole';

    use role SECURITYADMIN;
    use database identifier($dbname);

    grant select on future tables in schema myschema to role identifier($role);
```

I've also tried:

```sql
    grant select on future tables in schema identifier($dbname).myschema to role identifier($role);
```

but always get the same 'object not found' error.

I can hard code this to be:

```sql
    grant select on future tables in schema mydb.myschema to role identifier($role);
```

and that works fine, but defeats the point of having re-usable scripts if I have to hardcode the database name (the schemas bizarrely will be static across environments so fine to hard code).

Is this a limitation or am I doing something obviously wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me. I have a database called `test_db` with a schema called public. Who is the owner of your `myschema` schema?

```sql
set dbname = 'test_db';
set role = 'SYSADMIN';

use role SECURITYADMIN;
use database identifier($dbname);

grant select on future tables in schema public to role identifier($role);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. That code looks identical to mine so odd that it works for you. Maybe it is an ownership thing (the schemas are owned by our etl loader role) but I thought securityadmin had access to grant on all objects?

Comment: I wonder if your schema name is case-sensitive when you created the schema did you put the schema name in quotes? If you run `show schemas in database mydb` does the schema's name show as all capitals, all lower, or a mix of capital and lower?

Comment: No, the schema naming is all upper case, and if I hard coded the database in it worked fine. I think the issue was that, although the role SECURITYADMIN can grant access to any and all objects, it has to be specifically granted access to a schema itself to see it and grant on it. Something we hadn't done. Modified the scripts to provide future usage on all schemas for the role and now works fine. Not sure if this is the right way or not, but it works so I'm happy!! Thanks for taking a look with me though, your question regarding ownership definitely got me looking in the right place!